# System Colors not appearing in IBInspectable property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, nsview

In order to change the background color of an `NSView`, I subclassed `NSView` as:

```
@IBDesignable class ColoredView: NSView
{
    @IBInspectable var blockColor : NSColor = NSColor.windowBackgroundColor;

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
        blockColor.set();
        dirtyRect.fill();
    }
}
```

Then I set the Custom Class of a view to `ColoredView` in order to change its background color. The `IBInspectable` property - `blockColor` appears in the attributes inspector and I can change its color:

[image]

The problem is I can't use the System Colors or Named Asset Colors in this case as they do not appear in the menu:

[image]

Cannot seem to figure out what could be the problem here.